# how insert value into sql sever using java?

Tags: java, sql

sorry if my questions are identical. I was trying to find out online documentation but I still have not solved the problem. it's an error in the line "stmt.executeUpdate ();"

```
public class DBConnect {
    private List<SinhVien> result = new ArrayList<SinhVien>();
public void updateSQL(String masv, String malop, String ten,
            Date ngaysinh, String diachi) {
    try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://MyPC:1433;databasename=QLSV;username=sa;password=APASSWORD");         
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SinhVien(masv, malop, ten, ngaysinh, diachi) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
            stmt.setString(1, masv);
            stmt.setString(2, malop);
            stmt.setString(3, ten);
            stmt.setDate(4, ngaysinh);
            stmt.setString(5, diachi);          
            stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect();
        dbConnect.XuatDSSV();
        dbConnect.findSinhvienById("51003146");
        dbConnect.updateSQL("123", "malop", "ten", null, "diachi");

    }
```

Comment: Please post your exception!

Comment: But it looks like you missed closing paren in your statement... `VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` -- <-- there

Comment: thanks @ElliottFrisch ^^ i'm missed closing paren, I took all night to find fault, but I still do not solve the problem because I think eclipse will error without brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you store your query in a String. It would have been easier to read, and find the problem...

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO SinhVien"
    + "(masv, malop, ten, ngaysinh, diachi) "
    + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; // <-- You were missing the close paren.
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add connection.commit() after stmt.executeUpdate(). And please, post the exception.